# Magento 2.1.10 setStoreId vs. setCurrentStore?

Tags: magento-2.1, scope, store-id, magento-2.1.10

I inherited a Magento v 2.1.10 project and was curious what the difference is between setStoreId(0) and setCurrentStore(0)?

Besides setStoreId being derived from the ProductFactory while setCurrentStore is derived from the StoreManagerInterface it seems like the do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you can understand like this one :

`setStoreId(0)` : You can consider, this is the fields and use with the specific object.

`setCurrentStore(0)` : You can consider this is the set the scope of the work.

Answer (score 0):

These two fields are used in case you have many different stores
For example, you have two stores A and B. Store A is default. When creating a product in admin, you only choose to create it in store B, so when you save it, it will setCurrenStore as store A and setStoreId as B (ie this product is only displayed on store B but it is created at the time you are using it at store A)